# Run While Loop and check another table for variable before outputting data

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a while statement.  That loops through my "customer" table and outputs the data.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
echo ".$row['category_id'].<br>
.$row['name'].<br>
.$row['address'].<br>
.$row['status'].<br>"

}
```

This all works fine.
The problem I have is the "category_id" is stored as a number in the "customer" table and the different categories are stored with their unique numbers and associated written names in a seperate "category" table.

For example customer table has,
category id - 150
name - Stackoverflow
address - 123 Main Street
status - Active

For example category table has
id - 150
name - Message Board

As I run my while loop to output the customer data, I need to query the category table to get and display the "name" associated to category_id.

I figured a while loop in a while loop, what do you guys think?  I appreciate the help.

Comment: You could probably just update your query to join on `category_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do a MySQL join and get all the information at once: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT
    c.name,
    c.address,
    c.status,
    ca.name as category_name
FROM
    customer c
JOIN
    category ca
ON
    ca.id = c.category_id
```

And your PHP will look like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "$row[category_name]<br>
          $row[name]<br>
          $row[address]<br>
          $row['status']<br>";
}
```

Comment: Here is my current query syntax.  It is generated a "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" error.     $query = "SELECT c.last_edit, c.name, c.logo, c.city, c.state, c.zip, ca.name AS category_name FROM business c JOIN category ca ON ca.id=c.category_id WHERE c.city='$search_city' AND c.state='$search_state' ORDER BY c.last_edit DESC LIMIT $Limit_Outcome";

Comment: Holy Cow.... Got it.... I'm learning... thanks for the great help.... the error was in referencing "ca.id"..  God Bless you guys..... Thanks a billion...